# How to decide whether to keep the duplicate rows or remove them. I have two duplicate records but they refer to two different persons

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-preprocessing, duplicate-records

I am trying to build an NLP model on this data set where I have data from some accidents where I need to predict the Accident Level. There are a total of 13 duplicate rows. But on looking into them I figure out that they are for different people involved in the same accident. I am not sure if I should drop or keep them.

Here is a snapshot of those duplicate rows for the date 01-04-2016 00:00

[Preview Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy5X8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete them, if one of the relevant features for predicting accident level would be distorted by the duplicated rows. think of it, that one of these accidents would be an outlier, putting all the other workers also into the data set would result in weighting the outlier. If you have high enough data these 13 won't matter. I would rather check the occurences of your target outcome class accidents level. In example how many occurences of an accident level do we have.

The idea of recoding this duplicates into the amount of people hit in the accident, thus examining not the workers but the accident itself, would only be useful if you had a lot of workers hit in different accidents. So Ill guess deleting would be a better idea.

Comment: That sure makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: "If you have high enough data these 13 won't matter": in this case, what is the rationale for removing them, as not touching them would supposedly not change anything either?

Comment: True, if you have a general pattern within your data these 13 won't change that much probably, as long as you can be sure about these 13 really not affecting your model byweighting some cases more, due to being duplicates. But why do you want to have obvious false data in terms of duplicates in your data set ? 

 If you then get more duplicate data over time, this argument may change, so deleting is always safer, as long as someone is sure these are duplicates.

Comment: It depends on what is our unit of interest: accidents, or people involved in accidents. The data seem to be about people involved in accidents. If we're interested in accidents, then the issue may be way worse than the presence of duplicates (and even then, removing duplicates just like that is not necessarily a good option). In this case, more info is needed about how the sample has been collected and what is the purpose of the model. Now, if we want to model people involved in accidents, then we should absolutely not remove records about different people involved in the same accident.

Comment: Now, I missed your last paragraph; transforming the number of "duplicates" into a feature (number of people involved in the accident) may be indeed a good idea, However, if it's rare for an accident to involve more than 1 person, it does not necessarily mean it is a bad predictor, so I'd be a bit cautious about the last sentence of your answer.